# Angular request issues

Tags: angularjs

I got an old project based on angular v1.7.8 and have a simple task to add one more input similar to existing input on this form. Sounds easy, right?
I did it, it was almost the same so I just added new input the same way as old one was added, and it mostly works except one weird thing.

The current state shows well, but when you try to save it - only unchanged value is being sent. Like it was 1, then you change it to 2, you can see that it is 2 in request payload, it is 2 before angular internal functions for sending ajax, but somehow (in xhr.onload function), it is already 1. And it is already 1 in chrome request preview. (The old input works as intended)

So in chrome network -> headers -> Request payload it is correct,
in chrome network -> preview it is incorrect.

I am really confused, and don't know how to fix it using angular. I can send ajax request without using angular, but I need to understand why it works this way.

Comment: It is hard to help with a coding problem when the question contains none of the buggy code. The AngularJS framework uses its $http service to send XHR requests. XHR requests done outside of that service will not have the benefit of AngularJS data binding. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: Please add some code, otherwise its hard to determine what might be the problem